# Sort max score in time length of each player

Tags: mysql, sql

My Database structure

```
Table 'Player'   : column 'id'
Table 'Score'    : column 'player_id' , 'score' , 'time'
```

example data in Table 'Score'

```
   player_id       score             time
     1001           100      2000-01-01 00:00:00
     1001             3      2012-08-01 00:00:00
     1001            11      2012-08-02 00:00:00
     1002            80      2012-07-01 00:00:00
     1002             5      2012-08-01 00:00:00
     1003            90      2012-07-01 00:00:00
```

I try to use

```
SELECT * FROM Score WHERE MONTH(time) = MONTH(NOW()) ORDER BY score DESC
```

The result from Player 1001 will be multiple row of score 11 and 3.
How to sort and get only max score in time length that should be only score 11 of Player 1001

The result should be

```
   player_id       score             time
     1001            11      2012-08-02 00:00:00
     1002             5      2012-08-01 00:00:00
```

not

```
   player_id       score             time
     1001            11      2012-08-02 00:00:00
     1001             3      2012-08-01 00:00:00
     1002             5      2012-08-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT player_id, max(score) as max_score
FROM Score 
WHERE MONTH(time) = MONTH(NOW()) 
group by player_id
ORDER BY max_score DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT player_id, max(score) as score, month(time)
FROM Score 
WHERE MONTH(time) = MONTH(NOW()) 
GROUP BY Player_id, month(time)
ORDER BY score DESC
```